# Make a bullet follow a moving object at a certain speed using Pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Basically. I am trying to make a tower defense game and I need the towers to shoot at the enemy and for the bullet to follow that enemy at a certain speed until they hit it. I have already written all the code however I, for some reason, cannot get the 'tracking' method to work for the bullet. I thought I could do this simply by using polar to cartesian conversions however I must be over looking something as the bullet does not go anywhere near its target.

This is what I have:

```
def follow(self):
    dx = (self.rect.x + 4) - (self.target.rect.x + 15)
    dy = (self.rect.y + 4) - (self.target.rect.y + 15)
    angle = math.atan2(dy, dx)
    x = self.speed * math.cos(angle)
    y = self.speed * math.sin(angle)
    self.rect.x += x
    self.rect.y += y
```

Answer (score 2):

`self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y` are integral values. If you add an floating point value, which is less than 1.0, then the result won't change.

I recommend to use `pygame.math.Vector2` to mange the position in floating point coordinates.
Set the position of the bullet in the constructor:

```py
self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(self.rect.center)
```

Calculate the direction vector from the bullet to the target:

```py
dir = pygame.math.Vector2(self.target.rect.center) - self.pos
```

Use [`.length()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.length) to calculate the distance to the target. Calculate the normalized direction from the bullet to the target by dividing by `distance`. The normalized vector is a [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) with a length of 1.0:

```py
distance = dir.length()
if distance > 0:
    dir = dir / distance
```

Update the position and the rectangle. Ensure that the bullet doesn't "go through" the target, by limiting the movement of the bullet by the distance to the target (`min(distance, self.speed)`):

```py
self.pos += dir * min(distance, self.speed)
self.rect.center = self.pos
```

The code may look somehow like this:

```py
class Bullet:

    def __init__(self, [...]):

        self.rect = [...]

        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(self.rect.center)

    def follow(self):
        
        dir = pygame.math.Vector2(self.target.rect.center) - self.pos
        distance = dir.length()
        if distance > 0:
            dir = dir / distance

        self.pos += dir * min(distance, self.speed)
        self.rect.center = self.pos
```